# Any E-Readers suggestions that supports ACSM books and scribbles / drawings?

Tags: ebook-readers, annotations, adobe-reader, acsm

As titled, I have recently bought a couple of books across platforms that are ACSM-encrypted, and would like to see if there is any E-Readers that supports drawing annotations.

I have tried several ebook readers but was unable to find one. I would prefer drawing graphs and mathematical formulas along as I read, than simply a text note....

If not, any recommended note taking applications for such purpose? (as I am unable to, or actually very troublesome, to convert ACSM book to pdfs) Any recommendations would help.

Thanks in advance!!!